# How do I account for Google Cloud Firestore security rules in Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

If I create a Firebase Function, I am able to freely read and write to my Firestore database using:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
[...]
admin.firestore().collection("collection").add({"foo": "bar"});
```

While I see that the `firebase-functions` library provides a reference to `firestore`, I can't see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_) how this is used in a similar manner to add/update data with the constraints of security rules.

Is this the the class I should be using, or are there other means to adopt this security from within a Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that uses backend SDKs, such as Firebase Admin, or any of the Google Cloud SDKs, always bypass security rules.  This includes code running in Cloud Functions, which is considered "backend".  You can't use security security rule to limit their access.  Security rules only apply to access from the client SDKs, used along with Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I have since realised that the `firebase` library itself can be used in Cloud Functions so that regular access is adopted, at least for authentication, similar to a client side application. This may provide the needs of rules, etc. if I can't achieve the requirements I have solely with the Firestore REST API.